# pip install networkit error

Tags: python, terminal, pip, networkit

I'm using the `pip install networkit` provide by the networkit homepage, but I don't know what's going wrong here, the terminal keep showing this:

```
Downloading/unpacking networkit
  Downloading networkit-3.4.1.tar.gz (582kB): 582kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/sy/lzckft690rn8xfm2f1svp8p00000gn/T/pip_build_runze/networkit/setup.py) egg_info for package networkit
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/sy/lzckft690rn8xfm2f1svp8p00000gn/T/pip_build_runze/networkit/setup.py", line 2, in <module>
        from setup_util import *
      File "setup_util.py", line 3, in <module>
        from subprocess import DEVNULL
    ImportError: cannot import name DEVNULL
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/private/var/folders/sy/lzckft690rn8xfm2f1svp8p00000gn/T/pip_build_runze/networkit/setup.py", line 2, in <module>

    from setup_util import *

  File "setup_util.py", line 3, in <module>

    from subprocess import DEVNULL

ImportError: cannot import name DEVNULL

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/sy/lzckft690rn8xfm2f1svp8p00000gn/T/pip_build_runze/networkit
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/runze/.pip/pip.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Version you are trying to install is not compatible with version of python you are using.

It seems it made its way to python 3.3.something only - http://bugs.python.org/issue5870

Comment: Thank you very much, using the latest python 3 solved the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Using command "pip3 install networkit" would be fine.
Don't forget add other libraries networkit needed to python3 modular.