# Can't install NetworKit

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pip, networkit

I have been trying to figure out what the problem was for installing this module for a while and I'm stuck. The only related link I could find is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29004223/pip-install-networkit-error). I type in the command `sudo -E pip3 install networkit` into the terminal and here is what I am getting.

```
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-Qunused-arguments'
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-Qunused-arguments'
error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/9n/zhnv69nd7sv9fj9gsg64c1p00000gp/T/pip-build-l15ye4xm/networkit/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/9n/zhnv69nd7sv9fj9gsg64c1p00000gp/T/pip-25ou5_op-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/9n/zhnv69nd7sv9fj9gsg64c1p00000gp/T/pip-build-l15ye4xm/networkit
```

I was able to install all the python packages mentioned [here](https://networkit.iti.kit.edu/getting-started/) using pip. I have python 3.5, installed gcc5 using [macports](https://www.macports.org/), currently use Cython version 0.23.4, and installed OpenMP through Homebrew. I was able to find answers to most of the problems I ran into, but I can't seem to find one for this.

Edit: `which g++` produces /opt/local/bin/g++ and `echo ${CXX}` produces a blank line

Comment: The outputs of `which g++` and `echo ${CXX}` would probably be helpful.

Comment: I myself haven't yet been able to install NetworKit with GCC 5. Do you have the option to install GCC 4.9? Also, posting to the project mailing list will increase your chances for a solution: https://lists.ira.uni-karlsruhe.de/mailman/listinfo/networkit